# Find question for low-used tag and retag them.

Tags: discussion, retagging

Would it be correct to search after question which could be categorized under a not-so-much used tag, and then retagging them accordingly? Or should I discuss the scope of the tag before doing anything on my own?
When should such a tag be consider as a canditate for deletion instead?

Answer (score 1):

I find nothing wrong with that.  The only concern is that you may want to go slowly so that your retagging will not fill the top page.

*Edit: I changed the reply completely because the older reply was based on my misreading of the question.*

Comment: Until now, I don't want to change anything, but I tend to be a bit too optimistic and I fear that would want to give a chance to each tag, although some might not deserve it.

Comment: @Eldros: Oops, I may have misunderstood your question.  Do you want to _add_ some rarely used tags to questions?  In that case, I do not think there is anything wrong with that (but you may want to do it slowly so that the top page will not be filled with your retagging).  I had thought that you wanted to _remove_ rarely used tags.

Comment: exactly, that's what I want to do. Which were the part of my post which made me misunderstand my intent?

Comment: @Eldros: Probably I misread “which _could be_ categorized under a not-so-much used tag” in the question as “which _are_ categorized under a not-so-much used tag,” but I do not know how I did so.  Sorry for the confusion.